# fullcalendar not showing events php json

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, fullcalendar

My json return from .php is also not showing the events. 
I have tried many diffrent ways and read alot of similar posts. Maybe im missing something here...

My HTML file  Calendar.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='../css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet'
    media='print' />
<script src='../lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='../js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2014-09-12',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: "events.php",
        eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
        alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
            '(should probably update your database)');
    },

    loading: function(bool) {
        if (bool) $('#loading').show();
        else $('#loading').hide();
    }
    });

});


</script>
<style>
body {
    margin: 40px 10px;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
```

my events.php file:

```
<?php 
try {
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=diskstation;dbname=Sharp;charset=utf8', 'Username', 'Password');
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}$sql = "SELECT idCalendar, TeamName, Name, DateExecute, TimeStart, DateEnd, TimeEnd, AllDay FROM      Calendar T1 
    INNER JOIN TimeTable T2 on T1.TimeTableIdFK = T2.idTimeTable
    INNER JOIN Team T3 on T2.TeamIdFK = T3.idTeam
    INNER JOIN Offer T4 on T2.OfferIdFKtime = T4.idOffer
    INNER JOIN Customer_Offer T5 on T1.Customer_OfferIdFK = T5.idCustomer_Offer
    INNER JOIN Customer T6 on T5.CustomerIdFK = T6.idCustomer
    INNER JOIN Customername T7 on T6.CustomernameIdFK = T7.idCustomername";

$result = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//To output as-is json data result
header('Content-type: application/json');
//echo json_encode($result);

//Or if you need to edit/manipulate the result before output
foreach ($result as $row){
    $return[]=array('id'=>$row['idCalendar'],
                'title'=>$row['Name'].' - '.$row['TeamName'],
                'start'=>$row['DateExecute'].'T'.$row['TimeStart'],
                'end'=>$row['DateEnd'].'T'.$row['TimeEnd'],
                'allDay'=>$row['AllDay']);
}
$dbh = null;


echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

The Output is a well formatted json:

```
[{"id":"1","title":"B\u00fchler AG - Harte","start":"2014-09-14T06:00:00","end":"2014-09-15T12:00:00","allDay":"false"}]
```

But the Fullcalendar is not displaying the event.
When i just create a test.json file and insert the exact same string into the file, it works.
Is there a problem that my html file cannot call the .php file? they are both in the same folder.

I think i found the Problem. The json seemed good when i opened it with my HTML editor. But when i open events.php directly with the browser on the webserver i get an access denied.

I played around with diffrent users and their privilages and hosts.

So i changed the PDO connection with localhost and root password. That made my HTML editor not work anymore but now the calendar is showing the right events.

Comment: I noticed on the documentation it shows the following format: 

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: '/myfeed.php'
    });

How about trying to add the forward slash to the path?

Your JSON definitely work though.

Comment: i just have tried that...  didn't work. If i add the test.json file with the same json string, it opens. its somehow that the php does not work. i will try to wrap it in a function and see how that goes.